# C++ stringstream question, how can I make each line seperate

Tags: c++, logging, format, stringstream, ostream

I'm sorry the title may be inaccurate.I'm new to C++.
Here is my code and output...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class LogLine {
private:
    stringstream ss;
    string message;
public:
    ~LogLine() {
        ss << "\n";
        message = ss.str();
        cout << message;
        message = "";
    }
    template <class T>
    LogLine& operator<<(const T& thing) { 
        ss<< thing;
        return *this; 
    }
    LogLine& operator<<(std::ostream &(*manip)(std::ostream &)) { 
        manip(ss);
        return *this; 
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        LogLine log;
        cout<< "Line One"<<endl;
        log << "I'm " << 25 << " years old...."<<endl;
        cout<<"Line Two"<<endl;
        log << "I " << "Live in " << " Houston....";
        return 0;
}
```

Current output:

```
Line One
Line Two
I'm 25 years old....
I Live in  Houston....
```

Desired output:

```
Line One
I'm 25 years old....
Line Two
I Live in  Houston....
```

I hope in each line of "log" be able to detect the end of that line and print out current message, and then clean itself. I know the reason of current output, but I can't figure out how should I modify my code to get desired output.("endl" can be missing)
Thanks a lot for any comments.

As described above...

Comment: You don't print out what's logged until your log object is destroyed.  If you want it to output immediately, you need to output it immediately instead of storing it in a stringstream.

Comment: If I'm reading this question correctly, you don't want `LogLine` to print the entire log in the destructor, and you also don't want `LogLine` to print immediately.  You want it to print everytime a newline is logged.  Is this correct?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just do not wan it print immediately. I want it print out at end of each line.

Comment: @ShipengYang Then you need to make your `operator<<` overloads look for line breaks being printed so they can then flush the `stringstream` to `cout`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your comment. Do you mean to look for endl or /n? I considered to detect endl, while endl can be missing and it should still work as expected.

Comment: Return LogLine as LogLine&& instead of LogLine&, this will destruct it directly after the line.

Comment: The shown code demonstrates your knowledge of classes, constructors, destructors, overloads, and other medium-to-advanced C++ topics. That, and logic, is all that's needed to accomplish the desired task. If you cannot come up with the right logic, then [perhaps scheduling an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) will be helpful?

Comment: I think plan was to use temporary object of `LogLine`, For example:  `LogLine() << "I'm " << 25 << " years old....";` https://godbolt.org/z/TEfa3PPWa

Comment: @Alanaa yes, you will have to make your `operator<<` look for `'\n'` when called with a `std::string`, `const char*`, or `char`, and to look for `std::endl` when called with a function pointer. There is also `std::flush`, too.

Comment: @MarekR consider making this to an answer. Instead of returning LogLine as reference, you could return it as rvalue reference, forcing the destructor at the end of the line, if the value is not rebinded again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand you correctly, you want to detect the end of the statement, where log is used, and then append a `std::endl`.

My solution is similar to that one of @MarekR, but it forces a line break, when log is not rebound:

It does not detect "\n" and flushes it to `std::cout`, that would be contra productive on parallel `std::cout` calls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class LogLine {
    std::stringstream ss;
public:
    LogLine(LogLine&&) noexcept = default;
    LogLine() = default;

    ~LogLine()
    {
        if(ss && ss.peek() != -1){
            cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    template <class T>
    friend LogLine operator<<(LogLine& lhs, const T& thing)
    {
        lhs.ss << thing;
        return std::move(lhs);
    }

    template <class T>
    friend LogLine&& operator<<(LogLine && lhs, const T& thing)
    {
        lhs.ss << thing;
        return std::move(lhs);
    }
    LogLine&& operator<<(std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&))
    {
        manip(ss);
        return std::move(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    LogLine forced;
    cout << "Line One" << endl;
    forced << "I'm " << 25 << " years old....";
    cout << "Line Two" << endl;
    LogLine() << "I "  << "Live in " << " Houston...." << endl << endl << endl;
    forced << "forced 2";
    std::cout << "End of the sausage" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That what happens here is: every call to `operator<<` creates a temporary, which steals the resources of the original structure. Therefore, when it is not rebound, the destructor gets called directly after the line, flushing the `stringstream`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It works as expected. I have a quick question, why the return value of first operator is LogLine instead of LogLine&&. In my mind, I think the return value should be a temperate object.

Comment: It takes a reference, and therefore, it must "steal" the resource from the original, therefore I have to pass the value(-reference) to a move constructor, to construct a new value. The new value is an rvalue, but not a reference. So I must return it per value. Returning it as rvalue-reference, would create a dangling reference.